# Q: (ssg-wsg): Where is the 'Enrolments' and 'Assessment' API reference?

Tags: api

I've been looking through the tms-information-kit documentation found on https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/guides/1em38OkeU0Lmn7Vb6arMN7.

I understand that for Training Partners, the minimum level of integration with TPGateway can be found under Annex A:

- Course Runs API
- Enrolments
- Attendance
- Assessments

Your docs (https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/6kYpfJEWVb7NyYVVHvUmHi#) cover the 'Course Runs' and 'Attedance', but there is no corresponding documentation for 'Enrolments' and 'Assessment'. Could you direct me to the right place for these?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can find the requirement FAQs at https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/faq/ (Select TMS Requirement from the side nav)

For Enrolment and Assessments related APIs, it's under "Programmes for Individual" category.

Enrolment: https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/7KU1xrpxljJZnsIkJP6QNF/group/adg1EGw5xjv6Fs40BTrK8

Assessments: https://developer.ssg-wsg.sg/webapp/docs/product/7KU1xrpxljJZnsIkJP6QNF/group/3540ZmPQma3rcanoBfNYff